# ADF - Overriding default settings for locale

Tags: oracle11g, locale

We are writing a ADF application, and we are implementing internationalization. It looks like JavaVM doesn't recognize the Faroese locale (fa), and therefor uses the wrong date format.

Is there a way to override the locale specific date format in Oracle ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
Added: `<formatting-locale>da_DK</formatting-locale>` to trinidad-config.xml